# Переход из SurfaceView на другую Activity

Tags: android, java

Как такое сделать?

Пытался сделать при помощи Intent, но выдает ошибку мол тут оно не юзается. Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не может такого быть... Скорее всего вы что-то путаете и пытаетесь взять `Context` простым кастом из `SurfaceView` (как из Активити). Надо сделать так:

```
Context context = getContext(); 
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class); //а не new Intent(this, MyActivity.class)
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Все элементарное просто, спасибо огромное!